# Prepend backslash to selected characters with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

The code I use at the moment is ugly because I have to write "replace" separately for every special character.

```
var str = ":''>";
str.replace("'","\\'").replace(">","\\>");
```

I would like to prepend backslash  to **< > * ( ) and ?** through regex.

Comment: You could use something like `str = str.replace(/([<>*()?])/g, "\\$1");`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a regex that matches the characters with a character set, you could try:

```
str = str.replace(/([<>*()?])/g, "\\$1");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8ar3Z/

It matches any of the characters inside of the `[ ]` (the ones you specified), captures them with the surrounding `()` (so that it can be referenced as `$1` in the replaced text part), and then prepends with `\\`.

---

**UPDATE:**

As a suggestion from **Mr. @T.J.Crowder**, it is unnecessary to capture with `()`, changing `$1` to `$&`, written as:

```
str = str.replace(/[<>*()?]/g, "\\$&");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8ar3Z/1/

---

References:

- Regex character set: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-character-set
- `$1` and `$&` use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter

Comment: +1 (in fact, I was your first upvote!), but you don't need a capture group: `str = str.replace(/[<>*()?]/g, "\\$&");`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hmm interesting. I've never strayed from `$n`, so I didn't realize `$&` would work like that. Thanks, I'll update! And woah, you deserve a prize for being first, for sure... :)

Comment: @ Ian: Not like the capture group is doing any harm. :-) But perhaps it's *slightly* simpler for newbies without...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You're absolutely right though! And it doesn't hurt to include/explain both versions. Just to make sure I understand, if you were trying to capture two different things in the same regex, you'd **need** to use `$1` and `$2` (with `( )`), right? I just want to make sure I'm not thinking through this wrong

Comment: @ Ian: Yeah, `$&` is the *entire* matched substring (including any captures if you've used them). So for instance: `"123 456".replace(/\d(\d)?\d/g, "$& [$1]")` gives you `"123 [2] 456 [5]"` because `$&` is the entire match (`"123"` the first time, then `"456"` the second time) and `$1` is the capture group (`"2"` and `"5"`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I should've just tested...that makes perfect sense. Thanks :) (un)fortunately I don't have to work with regexes outside of SO too much, so I didn't want to assume (even after reading MDN docs)